# A case for multiple controllers/models?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am building a monitoring app. I have several categories, and each category has several monitors. An example of a monitor is a graph of CPU usage.

My question is about architecture. I'm trying to implement MVC to make future expansion of the project simple, but I've reached a dilemma. Either I

1. Have a separate Controller and Model for each monitor, or
2. Have one `MonitorController` object and one `MonitorModel` object, with one method per monitor

The downside of #1 is that

- I will have to define each route individually
- I will instantiate different controllers for each route, when each one basically has only one task to perform: call the model's `getData()` method. Essentially, so far, I've been able to use one route `/{category}/{monitor}` for all monitors, and the simplicity is nice.

The downsides of #2 are

- Inflexible
- The `MonitorModel` object will become huge and unmaintainable, as each chart's `getData()` method can be quite complex spanning dozens of lines.

What is the right approach here?

(By the way, I'm using PHP.)

Comment: Just realized I assumed this was asp.net mvc.  I think the gist is the same over all, but could you specify the technology you're doing this in so answers can be tailored to that specific case?

Comment: There are "multiple models" in properly implemented MVC or MVC-inspired design pattern. Model is a layer *(just like presentation layer, which is made up from controller, views and few other structures)*

Comment: I guess my question is, in this case is it correct to have many models, each which has only one method, the `getData` method? Or is that a sign of poor design?

Comment: It's perfectly reasonable to have multiple models.

Answer (score 1):

The first rule of models is keep them as simple as possible.  Put that dozens of lines of logic into another project and reference that in your mvc project.  Think of your MVC application as your UI, all of the "business logic" should be kept in a project which is entirely agnostic of how it will eventually get displayed.

Doing that will make it pretty clear that you should probably have a `Monitors` controller with a `Data` method, which takes some specifier for which monitor to display and produces a view for that monitor.  That would be the most directly MVC-way.

Now handling multiple different types of monitors!  A suite of `DisplayTemplates` which handle displaying each of the different types is the way to go.  Your view for `Data` essentially becomes `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x)`.  [Obligatory msdn link on using `DisplayTemplates`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308450%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

As a note, always pass a simple DTO to your views.  The simpler the better, this will make your life easier in the long run.

Now you'll have a nice cleanly sliced application where the different parts won't trample each other too much when things change.

Comment: I think your logic applies to my php project, but I'm not sure how the details work themselves out. Usually we have a User model, a BlogPost model, etc. Perhaps I should have a Data Model with many getData methods, but then have separate controllers for each monitor.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know a single thing about organizing code in php.  I don't even how php enables object oriented code.  In my mind, Monitor is an abstract class which has a getData method.  Different types of monitors implement getData differently and in your MVC application, getData is called in a rather agnostic fashion.  The whole point of design is to reduce the amount of information flying around to make it clear what the intent of the code is.

Comment: Right. So basically, I could have each monitor inherit from the abstract Monitor class, overriding the getData method with their own version?